# How do I animate a sliding UIView from the right side of a host UIView?

Tags: ios, swift3, uiviewanimation, drawer, snapkit

**Scenario:**

I've created an 'attributeView' (UITableView) that is a subview (i.e., a member UIViewController's view of a container UIViewController's view) to be displayed along the right corner of the parent view.

It is activated by a contextual (UITableView) menu's user selection (not seen).

[image]

**Goal:** To animate this UIView as a *sliding view* from the right edge of the screen.  
Basically, acting like a sliding drawer.

The following snapkit code positions the attributeView.  I was thinking of starting out with a zero-width view, then animating to to full width:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
...
let attributeView = viewControllerToPresent.view
let containerView = presentingViewController?.view

presentingViewController?.addChildViewController(viewControllerToPresent)
containerView?.addSubview(attributeView!)

attributeView?.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.width.equalTo(0.0)
    make.top.equalTo(containerView!).offset(00.0)
    make.right.equalTo(containerView!).offset(0.0)
    make.bottom.equalTo(containerView!).offset(0.0)
}

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3,
               animations: {
                attributeView?.snp.updateConstraints { (update) in
                    update.width.equalTo(320.0)
                }
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
})

viewControllerToPresent.didMove(toParentViewController: presentingViewController)
```

But this doesn't work. I've tried various means of using snapkit to animate the width.  But I can't get it to slide from the right edge into view.

What's the proper way to do this?   
Or must I resort to positioning the view manually without snapkit and go from there?

Comment: you simply make an IBoutlet **which is a constraint**.  In storyboard just hook it up.  and then animate it.  There are many QA about it on here, have a search!

Comment: We're not using storyboards.   This is in full source code.

Comment: oh you're trying to use snapkit ?!  suggest, just forget it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the left constraint so it starts off the screen.

```
attributeView?.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.width.equalTo(0.0)
    make.top.equalTo(containerView!).offset(00.0)
    make.right.equalTo(containerView!).offset(0.0)
    make.left.equalTo(containerView!.snp.right)
    make.bottom.equalTo(containerView!).offset(0.0)
}

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3,
           animations: {
            attributeView?.snp.updateConstraints { (update) in
                update.left.equalTo(containerView!.snp.right).offset(-320.0)
            }
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

Comment: I had to do some tweaking but eventually got some animation effect.